# What salary did Hitler draw as Führer?

Tags: hitler

Out of curiosity, what salary did Hitler draw as leader of the Nazi Party and Chancellor of Germany?

Comment: What salary do you think other autocrats are drawing? Do you think Kim Jong-un is paying things out of his wallet? Do you think Recep Tayyip Erdoğan has payed anything for constructing Ak Saray? Not that I am comparing them to Hitler, personally. But generally speaking, as a head of state (even in a democracy) many things are payed *for* you, so "salary" becomes rather meaningless.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adolf_Hitler%27s_wealth_and_income

Comment: Sure, it does. Still that doesn't mean he gets no salary. It is a job after all and one is entitled to a salary. I am curious what Hitler's was.

Comment: @DarshanChaudhary salary is more than just a lump sum of money you get to your bank account. All the other benefits are part of your renumeration as well. I'm pretty sure Hitler didn't have many (if any) private bills to pay after he took power, he'd have no need of money. Not that German Reichsmarks were all that useful, the currency was rather volatile.

Comment: I vote to reopen - the answer has turned out to be not trivial (at least in the sense of "not in wikipedia or any obvious plance" and somewhat complicated (cf. the bit about postage stamps).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

He had a salary of 60,000 Reichsmark per year. This was his salary as "Reichskanzler".

Furthermore he received an author's fee for his book "Mein Kampf".

See this [link](http://www.spiegel.de/spiegel/print/d-45197362.html).

Comment: Good source find. It should be noted that those 60k RM were for 1933, with later years likely to vary significantly both because of changes in his salary and the variations of Reichsmark market value. Also, the article you linked also makes it clear that his Chancellor salary was actually less than 1/20th of his total income in "Mein Kampf" royalties... (having that book being the obligatory present to each newlywed couple of course helped).